# OpenTK - transparency issue on VBO

Tags: c#, opengl, transparency, opentk

I just want to create an .obj file loader, which will load 3D objects. Everything went alright but when i try to load a transparent object i got a problem.

So, here is a picture of the issue. Transparency is working but i don't know why, there are triangles. I try to load different objects (with and without texture also) but i got this issue always.

[image: the issue with triangles]

[image: the issue with triangles]

here is my light settings:

```
class Light
{
    public static void SetLight()
    {
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.ColorMaterial);

        Vector4 position = new Vector4(0.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f, 1.0f);
        Vector4 ambient = new Vector4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        Vector4 diffuse = new Vector4(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        Vector4 specular = new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, position);
        GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Ambient, ambient);
        GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Diffuse, diffuse);
        GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Specular, specular);

    }

    public static void SetMaterial()
    {
        GL.Color4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);

        Vector4 ambient = new Vector4(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.5f);
        Vector4 diffuse = new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
        Vector4 specular = new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

        GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Ambient, ambient);
        GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Diffuse, diffuse);
        GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Specular, specular);
        GL.Material(MaterialFace.FrontAndBack, MaterialParameter.Shininess, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

and in the main Load function a also have these settings

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

//GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
//GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
```

i know that maybe my answer is not the best, but i don't know what is this issue and i don't even find similar issues on the net.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

[image]

You need to sort the transparent faces from the furthest to the closest before drawing them.

Comment: The depth test rejects fragments further away, but here, you must explicitly sort them, so the depth buffer is actually useless.

Comment: Right. Now I remember why I avoid transparent volumes.

Comment: It's the reason you never see a lot of transparency in games.

Comment: thx for the answers, i think i will avoid transparency in the future :D

Comment: Well if you do end up using it, the formula is distance = Math.Sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2)+(z1-z2)*(z1-z2)), calculate that for each face, sort the list from closest to furthest, and draw in that order.